# Use of the definite article with geboren to indicate a strong quality of a person

Tags: meaning

My question is about the meaning of the following examples (which I found on a dictionary):

1. sie ist **die** geborene Lehrerin
2. er ist **der** geborene Mathematiker

*I don't understand why the definite article is used, instead of the indefinite one.* Literally, at least to me, the above mean that the person being referred to is THE born teacher/mathematician among all teachers and mathematicians currently existing in the phenomenal world.

I strongly suspect that this is not the meaning German speakers find in the sentences above. Instead, I suppose they understand them as:

1. she is **a** born teacher
2. he is **a** born mathematician

The comparison between the German and English examples should make my question clear. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call someone *der/die geborene XY* does not mean that this person is the best XY in the world, but that this person has everything it takes to be an excellent XY, one couldn't wish for more. There might still be other specimen that are equally perfect for that position.
I believe this **is** stronger than the English ***a*** born XY, which would be expressed in German usually as *er/sie ist zum XY geboren*.

Comment: We might analogize it to how in English "a born mathematician" and "THE prototypical mathematician" or something. Similar meaning, but one uses the while the other uses a. Neither means the person is the best. Just means they satisfy all the desirable qualities.

Answer (score 1):

For me, *der geborene Lehrer* is like

> Er ist **der** typische deutsche Beamte.

meaning "he is the prototype of a German official" = the most typical specimen of the given species. It may be a special form of the general definite article. Other verbalisations of a similar idea are

> Sie ist **das** Musterexemplar einer treusorgenden Hausfrau und Mutter.
>
> **Der** Engländer als solcher gilt ja ... als Inbegriff von Heiterkeit und sorgloser Lebensfreude. (Internetfund)
>
> Sie ist **die** ideale Person für diesen Job.

Nowadays, you often hear Germans say

> XYZ ist **das beste Beispiel** dafür, dass ...

which does not mean "the very best and one and only example" but "I'm going to tell you now a very good example for what I have just said".

---

In Englisch kann ich das nicht gut ausdrücken. Der prototypischste Vertreter einer Art ist mit seiner optimalen Erfüllung der Art-Kriterien eben doch ein Einzelexemplar. Allerdings ist ein "geborener Mathematiker" mehr als ein Prototyp: Ihm war das Mathematiker-Sein von Natur aus mitgegeben, es ist seine natürliche Existenzweise. Man kann das in diesem Fall im Deutschen auch mit dem unbestimmten Artikel ausdrücken:

> Er ist ein geborener Verlierer.

Das heißt, als Looser ist er einer unter vielen, und dieses Auf-der-Verliererseite-Stehen haftete ihm von klein auf an. Erst der bestimmte Artikel wie in

> er ist **der** geborene Verlierer (= *der Verlierer schlechthin, ein Verlierer, wie er "im Buche steht"*)

macht aus ihm das Vorzeige- und Lehrbuchexemplar eines Verlierertypen.

Typenhaftigkeit kann je nach Kontext auch wie in

> das war mal wieder typisch Mann

durch den Nullartikel oder wie in

> eine richtige Hausfrau sieht den Dreck

durch den unbestimmten Artikel bezeichnet werden.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with

1. sie ist **eine** geborene Lehrerin
2. er ist **ein** geborener Mathematiker

In fact, it feels slightly more natural to me, and I would probably tend to use this form, for the reasons you mentioned.

To me, it isn't so much about comparing to others, but a quality of the person, both in ability and preference. For example, a person might be good at something, but not enjoy it. I wouldn't use this phrase for such a case.

Answer (score -6):

Man könnte vermuten that *geboren-* hier die Bürde, bzw. Würde (eigentlich nicht so schwer auseinander zu halten, eigentlich) eines Würdenträgers bezeichnete, so wie eine Geburt bzw Taufe erst nach Eintragung ins Kirchenbuch zu wichtigen Rechten berechtigt. En *to bear* wird in diesem Sinne viel vielfältiger verwendet, während die Wurzel im deutschen von *bergen* etc. verdrängt geworden zu sein scheint; *gebären* erscheint als Wort bzw als Vorgang viel seltener und wirkt daher auch schon bald wie eine Rückbildung aus *Geburt[stag], geboren*. Der zigste Geburtstag ist doch auch nicht der Tag, an dem man zum zigsten mal das Licht der Welt erblickt, sondern der, an dem einer *gebührend* gefeiert wird, und aus unerfindlichen Gründen just an jenen Tagen bestimmte Rechte oder Pflichten erwirbt oder verliert. In diesem Sinne wäre der gebührliche Virtuose wohl erst später als ein von Geburt an vorherbestimmter verstanden worden--um Nachweise werde ich mich ob der mangelhaften Quellenlage kaum bemühen. Nunmehr wird er aber ausschließlich so gedeutet. Und auch die Geburtstagsfeier ist nur ein Sinnbild kindlicher Naivität, die ob der geschenkten Aufmerksamkeit den Grund gar nicht hinterfragen mag.